# Oracle SQL sysdate with constant time

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]I have below query -

```
update esp_notification set start_date_time = TO_DATE('06-25-2020 12:15', 'MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi') where serial_number ='AUTOSMOK0489' and status = 'active';
```

For example-

06/24/2020-sysdate,
12:15 -systime.
Above mentioned numeric values are for example only.I will be always picking current sysdate and current systime for the first run only.
For the 2nd,3rd,4th..... run date should be decreasing by 1 and time must be same as first time run.

I would like to simplify my question as it seems confusing.

In the above query, I want to change Today's date-1 (i.e 06/22/2020)
and time should be constant i.e same as before (i.e 04:57) on each run.

```
Example-
On 1st execution-'06/24/2020 12:15'
On 2nd execution-'06/23/2020 12:15'
On 3rd execution-'06/22/2020 12:15'
On 4th execution-'06/21/2020 12:15'
On 5th execution-'06/20/2020 12:15'
On 6th execution-'06/19/2020 12:15'
On 7th execution-'06/18/2020 12:15'
```

After the query execution, it updates only one row.
How to modify the SQL query to achieve this?

```
I tried to execute the query like-
update esp_notification set start_date_time = TO_DATE(start_date_time-1, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi') where serial_number ='AUTOSMOK7879' and status = 'active';
```

But this query updates the 'start_date_time' column values randomly not setting the date-1 value.
DB has 'start_date_time' clumn value in '2020-07-01 03:43:30.0' format.

Comment: It is unclear how your need (decreasing a date) relates to this constant `TO_DATE` call.

Comment: Are you updating a single row that matches those conditions multiple times - if so why, and how many times? Or multiple rows that match with different dates - if so how many, and how do you decide which gets which date?

Comment: _After the query execution, it updates only one row. How to modify the SQL query to achieve this?_ - Do you mean only one row is affected (changed) or all updated rows share the same new value?

Comment: It updates the single row everytime.

Comment: Do you want to update a single row multiple times (by executing the statement multiple times) or update multiple rows a single time with decreasind dates?

Comment: I want to update a single row multiple times (by executing the statement multiple times). I attached the image file of database table in question for reference.

Comment: I hope I understood you the right way and updated my answer. I recognized a already set sysdate by the condition (minutes in row >= minutes current time - minute treshhold).

Comment: What do you mean by 'run' - are these all independent updates? If so how do you know where any update is the 'first run' or a later run? Unless the column starts of null, I'm not sure how you could tell - unless you have other logic and/or control that you haven't shown us.

Comment: When I say first run it means first-time query execution. There is a REST call that I have to do after the query execution which allows me to change the column date-timestamp to the date-time stamp which is I am using in the query. Anyway, I got the solution for this. The only thing I want to know here that if I use minus 1 in "2020-07-01 03:43:30.0-1" will this work for me? If this works then I would like to know whether it will minus the date(i.e date one day before) or it will subtract the time also with -1?

Comment: @RaghuNandan Why don't you try that yourself? Pseudocode: `select time, time-1 from dual`. Also, "2020-07-01 03:43:30.0-1" is no valid date.

Answer (score 0):

You can minus the `row_number` days from `sysdate` as follows:

```
UPDATE ESP
   SET
    START_DATE_TIME = (
        SELECT SYSDATE + 1 - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
             ORDER BY YOUR_PRIMARY_KEY
        )
          FROM ESP
         WHERE SERIAL_NUMBER = 'OK0489'
           AND STATUS = 'active'
    )
 WHERE SERIAL_NUMBER = 'OK0489'
   AND STATUS = 'active';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select trunc(sysdate + rownum) + interval '4' hour + interval '57' minute as dt
from dual 
connect by level <= 10;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your solution, besides user suggested to modify his query so this is not really a solution to his problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `rownum`as Tejash already described, but in a perhaps more random way:

```
update
    (select start_date_time, sysdate - rownum as new_time
    from esp_set
    where serial_number ='OK0489' and status = 'active')
set start_date_time = new_time;
```

This selects your desired data (inner select) and updates your `start_date_time` with the sysdate decreased by 1 per row further down. Plus you can see the result of the operation by only executing the select-statement.

EDIT:
After the comment *I want to update a single row multiple times (by executing the statement multiple times). I attached the image file of database table in question for reference.*:

first run:

```
update esp_notification set start_date_time = TO_DATE('06-25-2020 12:15', 'MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi') where serial_number ='AUTOSMOK0489' and status = 'active';
```

all following runs:

```
update esp_notification set start_date_time = start_date_time - 1 where serial_number ='AUTOSMOK0489' and status = 'active';
```

Or, if you really want to do it with a single statement:

```
create table chriz_tab
(
    dat date,
    id number(1)
);
insert into chriz_tab values (sysdate, 1);
insert into chriz_tab values (to_date('01.02.2015 09:10')/*some random date*/, 2);

update chriz_tab 
set dat = case
            when TO_CHAR(dat,'HH24')*60 + TO_CHAR(dat,'MI') >= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24')*60 + TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MI') - 5/*<-how many minutes this should work before setting sysdate again*//60
            then
                dat - 1
            else
                sysdate
            end
where id = 1;
/
select chriz_Tab.*
from chriz_tab; -> i.e. 01.07.20 13:56:02, 30.06.20 13:56:02, 29.06.20 13:56:02....
```

which translates to the following for you

```
update esp_notification 
set start_date_time = case
            when TO_CHAR(start_date_time,'HH24')*60 + TO_CHAR(start_date_time,'MI') >= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24')*60 + TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MI') - 5/*<-how many minutes this should work before setting sysdate again*//60
            then
                start_date_time - 1
            else
                sysdate
            end
where serial_number ='AUTOSMOK0489' and status = 'active';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query
`update esp SET to_date((to_char(SYSDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY')||' 04:57'),'MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi') where serial_number ='OK0489' and status = 'active';`

Answer (score 0):

Use CONNECT-BY to obtain a range of rows, then use interval arithmetic:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - LEVEL + INTERVAL '01 4:57' DAY TO MINUTE AS DT
  FROM DUAL 
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4166b9dc4cc2fd38436b6f509ef35b82)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column value is null before the first run, you can use a case expression to decide whether to set it to the current system or to subtract a day:

```
update esp_notification
set start_date_time =
  case
    when start_date_time is null then sysdate
    else start_date_time - 1
  end
where serial_number ='AUTOSMOK0489' and status = 'active';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=188f61c1750ea3bde3da67886ff8d6fb) with short pauses between updates just to demonstrate that the original time part is being preserved.

If the column isn't null before the first run then you need some other way to identify whether an update is the 'first' or not - possibly from other columns that you will update as part of the same statement, for example; but we can only speculate.

> I am able to resolve the issue by below query which updates only date not time.
>
> ```
> update esp_notification set start_date_time = 
> ((select start_date_time-1 from esp_notification where serial_number ='AUTOSMOK7879' and status = 'active')) where serial_number ='AUTOSMOK7879' and status = 'active';
> ```

You don't need the subquery; you can use a simplified version of my query above:

```
update esp_notification
set start_date_time = start_date_time - 1
where serial_number ='AUTOSMOK0489' and status = 'active';
```

But this doesn't handle your 'first run' requirement...

In both cases this uses [datetime/interval](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705). If you have a date value and add or subtract a number, that number represents the number of whole or partial days; so subtracting 1 goes back a day, while adding 0.25 goes forward 6 hours.

If you have a timestamp then adding/subtracting a number implicitly converts the timestamp to a date first, losing fractional seconds and timezone information (if present). Depending on what you are doing with it, it may be implicitly converted back to a timestamp, or even a time stamp with timezone, which will pick up the session time zone. That could leave you with a significantly different value than you started with.

With timestamps you should use an interval, and as you can do that for dates too, you can change the update to:

```
update esp_notification
set start_date_time = start_date_time - interval '1' day
where serial_number ='AUTOSMOK0489' and status = 'active';
```

to cover both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue by below query which updates only date not time.

```
update esp_notification set start_date_time = 
((select start_date_time-1 from esp_notification where serial_number ='AUTOSMOK7879' and status = 'active')) where serial_number ='AUTOSMOK7879' and status = 'active';
```